# How do I get a full URL in a image drop event

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a full URL using getData() after a drop event of an image:

```
function drop(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = e.dataTransfer.getData("url") || e.dataTransfer.getData("text/uri-list");
    alert(url);
...
}
```

When I drop my image and capture the event my `url = "http://localhost"` and does not include the full url to the image.  What is the correct way to capture the full url from a dropped image?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this writing there is no way to get the full path of an uploaded file. The File API **does not** provide the full path name. This is what the specification says

> The name of the file; on getting, this must return the name of the file as a string. There are numerous file name variations on different systems; this is merely the name of the file, without path information.

So there is no way you can get it as of now. This is done for **security concerns**.

Hope that helps :)